# Using the zero conditional to talk about one instance

Tags: conditionals

Can't the zero conditional talk about one instance?, maybe I want to say:

> If I want to get a job, I'll have to study a lot.

my intention isn't to use the first conditional in the above example, because that would mean the condition concerns the future, I want the condition to talk about the **present**, because I may have more knowledge in the future than now. I also don't want the sentence to express something that is **always** true, for the same reason, I may have more knowledge in the future that qualify me for a job. So, does the sentence above talk about **one** instance/case?, and does the condition talk about the present?, and is that what is meant by the paragraph below?, from wikipedia:

> Contradiction between the zero and first conditional: There is a
> problem when the condition refers to the present, but the consequence
> to the future, as in these examples:
>
> If you are young, you will like that book. (I do not know how old
> you are.)
>
> If you are already so good at it, you will be a master in one year.
>
> If he is already here, you will find him.
>
> Formally, every sentence above looks like the first conditional, with the condition
> having future meaning,[5] which was not our intention. Generally,
> context and auxiliary words like "already", "at present", etc.
> sometimes are enough to inform us that the condition has present
> meaning, but sometimes are not, which leads to ambiguity, for example:
>
> If you do it now, you will not have to do it later. The word "now" can
> be interpreted as "at present" or "in the immediate future". Hence,
> the condition can refer both to the present and future.
> [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Mixed_conditional).

Comment: Similarly, your condition "if I want to get a job" can refer both to the present and future. You might want a job now or in the near future.

Comment: If the zero conditional is something that is always true, I don't think your sentence is it because it refers to your qualifications and job prospects at this moment.

Comment: @KateBunting: By that token, you're saying OP's *exact* example is ***not*** a "zero conditional", but it would become so if the subject switched to *If **one** wants to get a job, **one** will have to study a lot.* Or the same thing with ***you***, which might mean the specific addressee, OR "anyone". It's things like that that make me think these "numbered conditionals" aren't necessarily useful classifications. Certainly I never had to know any of this to learn English as a native speaker.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Neither did  I - I had to look up what 'zero conditional' meant!

Comment: @KateBunting: John Lawler is "the horse's mouth" for me here, and I don't think he's ever had a good word to say about numbered conditionals. I'm not ashamed to say that I probably looked up 'zero conditional' for at least the twentieth time just now - and I'll do it again in the future, because it's not useful enough to me to bother remembering (and the actual *numbers* mean nothing to me - they're just indexes into a pointless list).